# Do I need to make two calls to listen() for a web socket, http server setup in Tornado?

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

I have a web app that serves HTTP traffic on port 80, but also establishes a WebSocket connection on port 8888 to the client. The client issues an HTTP request for `index.html` on port 80, and the returned HTML page establishes a socket connection to my servers IP on port 8888 to retrieve real-time data for updating some D3 graphs. Do I have to call listen for both WebSocket and web server as shown below? I've looked around and saw some apps that have WebSockets yet only call `listen()` for the HTTP server, so how does that work?

```
application = web.Application([
    (r'/', Index),
    (r'/websocket', WebSocketHandler)
    ], debug=DEBUG)
http_server = httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
http_server.listen(80)
application.listen(8888)
ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Answer (score 0):

WebSocket protocol is designed to be served from a HTTP server.
You can serve both HTTP and WebSocket requests from the same port.

Just call

```
application.listen(80)
```

and connect you WebSocket connection to port 80.